# Kalman filter 3D implementation

Tags: opencv, kalman-filter

I want to implement the kalman filter for a moving object in r3 (X,Y,Z-coordinate) in OpenCV.
I tried to understand the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d6a/classcv_1_1KalmanFilter.html#gsc.tab=0) but this is really not helpful and very rare.

The syntax for the initialization is:

> KalmanFilter::KalmanFilter    (   int     dynamParams, int    measureParams, int
>     controlParams = 0, int  type = CV_32F  )

In my case, is **dynamParams = 9** and **measureParams=3**?

And what is the **transitionMatrix** in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that for the 3D-Case often the position, velocity and acceleration is used. That means, that for the OpenCV implementation dynamParams=9 and measureParams=3 is right.

Answer (score 2):

In that case the Transition Matrix A looks like:

```
A = [1, 0, 0, v, 0, 0, a, 0, 0;
     0, 1, 0, 0, v, 0, 0, a, 0;
     0, 0, 1, 0, 0, v, 0, 0, a;
     0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, v, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, v, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, v;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

With

```
v = dt
a = 0.5*dt^2
```

See http://campar.in.tum.de/Chair/KalmanFilter